# Can't solve lifetime problem in simple method

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm brand new at Rust, coming from Java and I experience some difficulties with owenership and lifetimes. I'd like to do some formal calculus but obviously I'm not doing things the right way... Can you please show me why?

In my code I define those:

```
pub trait Function {
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Box<dyn Function>;
}

pub struct Add<'a>(&'a Box<dyn Function>, &'a Box<dyn Function>);

impl<'a> Function for Add<'a> {
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Box<dyn Function> {
        let x = self.0.differentiate();
        let y = self.1.differentiate();
        let add = Add(&x, &y);
        Box::new(add)
    }
```

Compiler tells me I have a borrowing problem with `x` and `y`, I understand why but can't figure out how to solve it; I tried to set `let x: Box<dyn Function + 'a> = ...` but then I got lifetime problems on defining add and on the last line:

```
expected `Box<(dyn Function + 'static)>`
              found `Box<dyn Function>`
```

Comment: Not sure why you are returning the reference to the box. In your case you should be returning the Box the `&` is not needed at all

Comment: The other thing is that your API construction is a bit odd.  Are you trying to implement differentiate for the type that will implement Function?

Comment: Just a general remark for understanding lifetimes: Annotating lifetimes does *not* make objects live longer or keep them alive. The other way round, lifetimes are there to track how long an object is *required* to be alive.

Comment: Also in general: `&Box<T>` is a construct that is very unusual and, to me, indicates a mistake in the code layout. It is usually used as owned `Box<T>` or as referenced `&T`. There is no reason to include the `Box` in the reference, because you can borrow a `&T` from a `Box<T>`.

Comment: Here is an example using the `Box<dyn>`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7dfbb89c5a1f4a49e1bbbc824cddc710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return an object that references local variables.

This is nothing special to Rust, it is like that in every language that has references (Java doesn't, in Java everything is a reference counting smart pointer). Writing this in C/C++ would be undefined behaviour. The borrow checker is here to prevent undefined behaviour, so it rightfully complains.

Here is a wild guess of what you might have wanted to do.

I'm unsure why you use references here, so I removed them. Your code looks like `Add` should own its members.

```rust
pub trait Function {
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Box<dyn Function>;
}

pub struct Add(Box<dyn Function>, Box<dyn Function>);

impl Function for Add {
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Box<dyn Function> {
        let x = self.0.differentiate();
        let y = self.1.differentiate();
        let add = Add(x, y);
        Box::new(add)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative design would be to require differentiable functions to be clonable (because you'll probably want to be able to use them in different places), and avoid dynamic dispatch (and the indirection required by trait objects) altogether. Here is the implementation of two simple operations as an example.

```rust
trait Differentiable: Clone {
    type Output;
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Add<L, R>(L, R);

impl<L: Differentiable, R: Differentiable> Differentiable for Add<L, R> {
    type Output = Add<L::Output, R::Output>;
    
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Self::Output {
        Add(self.0.differentiate(), self.1.differentiate())
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Mul<L, R>(L, R);

impl<L: Differentiable, R: Differentiable> Differentiable for Mul<L, R> {
    type Output = Add<Mul<L::Output, R>, Mul<L, R::Output>>;
    
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Self::Output {
        Add(Mul(self.0.differentiate(), self.1.clone()), Mul(self.0.clone(), self.1.differentiate()))
    }
}
```

Note that this easily allows adding useful constraints, such as making them callable (if you actually want to be able to evaluate them) or stuff like that. These, alongside with the identify function and the constant function should probably be enough for you to "create" polynomial calculus.

Comment: Although one could argue that this would be the perfect place for `Rc`.

Comment: Here the continuation of the concept you show here, with `X` and `IntValue`and `evaluatable`. Maybe this helps OP understand the concept: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=18e13bd32ddbedc3851080d89303b9ed

Comment: But after thinking about it, I think having a `Box<dyn>` approach might be more flexible when it comes to pruning (like removing `+ 0` or `* 1`). Having a fully typed tree would then make it hard to perform those things.

Comment: @Finomnis I think the proper way to do this would be to use dynamic dispatch when you consume, and generics when you write the library, pretty much as with iterators.

Comment: After thinking about it further, I almost fell like the most useful way would be to make this an enum, like serde_json.

Comment: @Finomnis yes, at this point I think it really depends on whether the OP wants others to be able to add new functions, or if they are happy with a predefined set of possible functions, in which case enums are probably the best indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to remove the references, because your Box is a smart pointer. So:

```rust
pub trait Function {
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Box<dyn Function>;
}

pub struct Add(Box<dyn Function>, Box<dyn Function>);

impl Function for Add {
    fn differentiate(&self) -> Box<dyn Function> {
        let x = self.0.differentiate();
        let y = self.1.differentiate();
        Box::new(Add(x, y))
    }
}
```

I think what you are trying to return a type after adding two types that implement differentiation.

There are a few different ways to think about this... Here's one:

```rust
pub trait Differentiable {
    type Result;
    fn differentiate(self) -> Self::Result;
}

pub struct Add<OP1, OP2>(OP1, OP2);

impl<OP1, OP2> Differentiable for Add<OP1, OP2>
where
    OP1: Differentiable,
    OP2: Differentiable,
{
    type Result = Add<OP1::Result, OP2::Result>;

    fn differentiate(self) -> Self::Result {
        let x = self.0.differentiate();
        let y = self.1.differentiate();
        Add(x, y)
    }
}
```